# Tfs commit to all branches?

Tags: tfs

let's assume that I have master and 2 branches. 
Master is enviroment from fixes are prepared to production server.
And when I do fix on master I'd like to commit this changes to all branches.
How to do it?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: Tfvc and visual studio :) how to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a single step. You have to merge the changesets (the fix commit to master) twice for each branch.

```
c:\projects>tf merge /version:C137~C137 Main branch1 /recursive

c:\projects>tf merge /version:C137~C137 Main branch2 /recursive
```

The [tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) applies changes **from one branch into another.**

Comment: C137-c137 is a range? May I try to marge more changsets then one? For ex: c137-c139?

Comment: @tylkonachwile Yes it's a range which you could add continuous changeset IDs. The example is showing how to only assign one single changeset.

Comment: Where is the right place to type this commands? I've been always using gui?

Comment: @tylkonachwile You could run the command in local mapping path of your branch by using Developer Command Prompt for VS201X. A easy way to find your branch local path--click the branch in source control explorer, there is a **local path**.